# getting code E401 error after running 'npm install'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, visual-studio-code, npm

I'm trying to clone a ReactJs project by git clone, and after open the project in VS CODE and run 'num install' I'm facing with code E401 error with the following sentence:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.
npm ERR! To correct this please trying logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login
```

after I try to login I'm getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - PUT https://...
```

I saw that my account in vs code in not connected, so I logged in and still same error.
After a few hours of searching for a solution I realized that it was related to the .npmrc file, because other projects that doesn't have the npmrc file works fine, but I can't understand what is the problem exactly.

My .npmrc file is look like:

```
registry=https://...
                        
always-auth=true
```

I'm tried to remove it, and delete package-lock.json and still not working.

Comment: What registry are you using?

Comment: Hey, the registry is for npm package that I created.
Another thing that I see in my windows pc is a .npmrc file in path C:\Users\<my-user-name>, maybe I missing this file in my mac pc?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it! If anyone is having this problem, for me the problem was my npm registry url. You can check your registry by the following command:

```
npm get registry
```

By default this url should point to the public npm registry at https://registry.npmjs.org/.
If you want to change the npm registry, you can use the following command:

```
npm set registry https://your-registry-url
```

After this, `npm install` finished without any error.